# jquery autocomplete with custom scroller not working

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, scroller

I need to use jQuery mCustomScrollbar function  for auto complete list.For simple content its work but not working in this case.
Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: Could you please provide more details. Which scenario its not working? It will be great if you can provide a jsfiddle link.

Answer (score 0):

for adding scroll bar for para 
add following line in css for that para.

```
  <div id="itemsdiv" style="display: block; max-height: 130px; width: 170px; overflow: auto; ">
//here is content
</div>
```